# How to rollback only the last session.add action in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am making a function to get a specific user from a database table User, or create it if it does not exist:

```py
def get_user_id(session, username):
    query = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username)
    try:
        user = query.one()
    except NoResultFound as e:
        user = User(username=username)
        try:
            session.add(user)
            session.flush()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            session.rollback() # ! This will rollback all changes made to the session.
            user = query.one()
    return user.id_user
```

The user create part might fail if the same username is created during the transaction, as it has a unique constraint. In that case, I query the existing id. However, I need to add rollback so that the session does not raise an error when commiting.

I want to be able to call the function multiple times during the same session without committing between calls. However, the rollback will undo all the previous additions of users or other modifications done before calling the function. Is there a way I can rollback only the user added in the current function call?

Comment: Depending on the database you are using you may be able to create a [savepoint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint) to enable a partial rollback.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I am using postgresql.  Also, do you know how can I handle the rare event where the user is deleted again, just before doing the second query in the last except block?

Comment: I have searched it, and what you suggest seems to be deprecateded: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#nesting-of-transaction-blocks

Comment: Those deprecations are for "nested transactions" where a second "full" transaction is started within an existing transaction. The use of savepoints is not deprecated.

Comment: And what about handling deletions in the last except?

Comment: You mean "deletions" resulting from the `.rollback()` ?

Comment: Not from the callback, but from another process that might be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but I faced a similar problem in a fastapi project

```
@api.post("/add_objs")
async def bulk_addition(deps): 
    for ip in ip_lst.ips:
        with db.begin_nested() as session:
            try:
                # add new entry in the table and rollback if it is a duplicate one 
                db.add(Obj(foo=foo, bar=bar))
                db.flush()
            except IntegrityError as err:
                session.rollback()
                continue
    db.commit()
```

from the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint) as referenced by @Gord Thompson

> Each time Session.begin_nested() is called, a new “BEGIN SAVEPOINT” command is emitted to the database within the scope of the current database transaction (starting one if not already in progress),

it creates a save point that can be used to catch per-instance errors